# How do I make the JavaScript canvas cover the whole screen?

Tags: javascript, html, css

```js
(function() {
  // Creates a new canvas element and appends it as a child
  // to the parent element, and returns the reference to
  // the newly created canvas element


  function createCanvas(parent, width, height) {
    var canvas = {};
    canvas.node = document.createElement('canvas');
    canvas.context = canvas.node.getContext('2d');
    canvas.node.width = width || 100;
    canvas.node.height = height || 100;
    parent.appendChild(canvas.node);
    return canvas;
  }

  function init(container, width, height, fillColor) {
    var canvas = createCanvas(container, width, height);
    var ctx = canvas.context;
    // define a custom fillCircle method
    ctx.fillCircle = function(x, y, radius, fillColor) {
      this.fillStyle = fillColor;
      this.beginPath();
      this.moveTo(x, y);
      this.arc(x, y, radius, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
      this.fill();
    };
    ctx.clearTo = function(fillColor) {
      ctx.fillStyle = fillColor;
      ctx.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);
    };
    ctx.clearTo(fillColor || "black");

    // bind mouse events
    canvas.node.onmousemove = function(e) {
      if (!canvas.isDrawing) {
        return;
      }
      var x = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
      var y = e.pageY - this.offsetTop;
      var radius = 40; // or whatever
      var fillColor = '#ff0000';
      ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-out';
      ctx.fillCircle(x, y, radius, fillColor);
    };
    canvas.node.onmousedown = function(e) {
      canvas.isDrawing = false;
    };
    canvas.node.onmouseup = function(e) {
      canvas.isDrawing = true;
    };
  }

  var container = document.getElementById('canvas');
  init(container, 531, 438, 'black');

})();
```

```css
#canvas {
  /* background:url(); */
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: rgb(224, 255, 226);
}
```

```html
<div id="canvas"></div>
```

I'm starting out quite new to coding, I'm trying to get the JavaScript to cover the whole of the rgb(224, 255, 226) - that mint looking color. So basically I want to whole thing back. Please help and thank you in advance for the help :)

This is code I found on the internet, I tried to find the person that made it to ask them but they did not reply

Comment: Initially the `height` and `width` of the `canvas` must be set in HTML via attributes. Also, `<canvas>` is HTML, not JavaScript.

Comment: @MayaWright : Just a friendly suggestion, you may want to mark Scott's answer as correct, simply based on how much effort this person put in comparatively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `init()`, instead of passing static values for width and height, pass the size of the window.

```js
(function() {
  // Creates a new canvas element and appends it as a child
  // to the parent element, and returns the reference to
  // the newly created canvas element


  function createCanvas(parent, width, height) {
    var canvas = {};
    canvas.node = document.createElement('canvas');
    canvas.context = canvas.node.getContext('2d');
    canvas.node.width = width || 100;
    canvas.node.height = height || 100;
    parent.appendChild(canvas.node);
    return canvas;
  }

  function init(container, width, height, fillColor) {
    var canvas = createCanvas(container, width, height);
    var ctx = canvas.context;
    // define a custom fillCircle method
    ctx.fillCircle = function(x, y, radius, fillColor) {
      this.fillStyle = fillColor;
      this.beginPath();
      this.moveTo(x, y);
      this.arc(x, y, radius, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
      this.fill();
    };
    ctx.clearTo = function(fillColor) {
      ctx.fillStyle = fillColor;
      ctx.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);
    };
    ctx.clearTo(fillColor || "black");

    // bind mouse events
    canvas.node.onmousemove = function(e) {
      if (!canvas.isDrawing) {
        return;
      }
      var x = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
      var y = e.pageY - this.offsetTop;
      var radius = 40; // or whatever
      var fillColor = '#ff0000';
      ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-out';
      ctx.fillCircle(x, y, radius, fillColor);
    };
    canvas.node.onmousedown = function(e) {
      canvas.isDrawing = false;
    };
    canvas.node.onmouseup = function(e) {
      canvas.isDrawing = true;
    };
  }

  var container = document.getElementById('canvas');
  
  // Instead of passing static values for width and height,
  // pass the size of the window.
  init(container, window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight, 'black');

})();
```

```css
#canvas {
  /* background:url(); */
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: rgb(224, 255, 226);
}
```

```html
<div id="canvas" height="50" width="50"></div>
```

Answer (score -2):

You need to pass window.innerWidth and window.innerHeight as parameters to init function.

```js
(function() {
  // Creates a new canvas element and appends it as a child
  // to the parent element, and returns the reference to
  // the newly created canvas element


  function createCanvas(parent, width, height) {
    var canvas = {};
    canvas.node = document.createElement('canvas');
    canvas.context = canvas.node.getContext('2d');
    canvas.node.width = width || 100;
    canvas.node.height = height || 100;
    parent.appendChild(canvas.node);
    return canvas;
  }

  function init(container, width, height, fillColor) {
    var canvas = createCanvas(container, width, height);
    var ctx = canvas.context;
    // define a custom fillCircle method
    ctx.fillCircle = function(x, y, radius, fillColor) {
      this.fillStyle = fillColor;
      this.beginPath();
      this.moveTo(x, y);
      this.arc(x, y, radius, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
      this.fill();
    };
    ctx.clearTo = function(fillColor) {
      ctx.fillStyle = fillColor;
      ctx.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);
    };
    ctx.clearTo(fillColor || "black");

    // bind mouse events
    canvas.node.onmousemove = function(e) {
      if (!canvas.isDrawing) {
        return;
      }
      var x = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
      var y = e.pageY - this.offsetTop;
      var radius = 40; // or whatever
      var fillColor = '#ff0000';
      ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-out';
      ctx.fillCircle(x, y, radius, fillColor);
    };
    canvas.node.onmousedown = function(e) {
      canvas.isDrawing = false;
    };
    canvas.node.onmouseup = function(e) {
      canvas.isDrawing = true;
    };
  }

  var container = document.getElementById('canvas');
  init(container, window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight, 'black');

})();
```

```html
<div id="canvas"></div>
```

Comment: This is the same solution that I posted several minutes ago, except you didn't even both to explain what you did.

Comment: Sorry for not explaining

Comment: It's still the same answer as one that was already posted.

Comment: Can you please check the code in some browser?. It's working for me

Comment: Thank you both for helping me :)

Comment: @MayaWright You're welcome. Please consider marking my answer (the first one) as "the" answer by clicking the check mark at the top-left of the answer.